# Union. User-Defined Constructor or non-trivial default constructor

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, constructor, unions

Current Error: vec4 has a user-defined constructor or non-trivial default constructor.

Hello,

I looked up a few things on this bug, by going into what a non-trivial default constructor is and got no where. The code is currently this

```
union 
{
    float elements[4 * 4];
    vec4 columns[4];
};
```

To my current knowledge as long as i was to flag the constructor as default i would be fine which i did here.

```
    vec4() = default;
    vec4(const float& x, const float& y, const float& z, const float& w);
```

If anyone has any knowledge on what is going on here, or can help can help me reach a conclusion that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: [Can not reproduce with g++.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/966b5d6da367a4de)

Comment: @orlp Ugh.. MSVC strikes again throwing errors that are not real. The sad part is it won't even let me build.

Comment: MSVC C++11 relaxed union constraints are not finished.  They are closer in 2015.

Comment: @Yakk so is there a solution for this right now?

Comment: @ZakStrange Don't use MSVC or change your code.

Comment: Or write a manual union with placement new, etc.